# Change outcome of equation with variable that affects other variable

Tags: functions, logic

I have a formula for resolution of output an electronic device output that has one input that is max_steps

```
resolution = max_frequency / max_steps
```

max_frequency is not an input, but is only used for calculating a different, unrelated, input, thus if I wish to set resolution I need to vary max_steps

However the formula for max_steps

```
max_steps = (max_frequency * 8250) / 65,536
```

means that varying max_steps also changes  max_frequency... which means (by the first form) that resolution changes... which is what I wanted to set...

Is there a name for this type of problem? A way of solving it so that I can set resolution?

Comment: What do 8250 and 65536 represent in the formula? Are you willing to change one or both of them?

Comment: @Kevin, These are constants set by the system - 65,536 = 2^8 as there are 8 bits, 8250 is the sampling rate which is dependent upon an interrupt which occurs at a frequency of 8.25 kHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to answer to your question by changing notation a bit. 
Let $q$ be max_steps, $f$ be max_frequency and $r$ be resolution. Then you have

$r=\frac{f}{q}$ (*)

and

$f=\frac{65536* q}{8250}$ (**).

The relation (**) implies that max_frequency is actually a *function* of max_steps, in symbols

$f=f(q)$.

If max_steps varies, then max_frequency varies, as described in (**), which expresses a linear relation between max_steps and max_frequency.

The question now is: is the resolution $r$ dependent of max_steps, as well?
Answer: no.

In fact, if we use the definition of frequency given in (**) 
and we put it in  ( * ) we arrive at

$r=\frac{f}{q}=\frac{f}{q}=\frac{\frac{65536* q}{8250}}{q}=\frac{65536}{8250}=7.94$,

which is a constant (above we supposed that max_steps is different from $0$).

I hope it helps.

Comment: So essentially, with the 8250 being fixed then r is also fixed and if it was variable also, then resolution would be variable? ... hmmm, thanks, I'll have to remove variable resolution control from the system then I guess

Comment: I interpreted 8250 and 65536  as  numbers. To me $r$ is a constant, given by the ratio $\frac{65536}{8250}$. You can upvote and flag the answer if it was helpful to you. In case of other questions, just ask :-)